# codeigniter: I can't change view page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having some problems changing the view page in the code. Note: i'm using ajax.

This is part of the controller function called "insert_inventario" after the information is saved in array_db it compares with the inventario_model and the result "true" or "false" is saved in obj_inv.

```
$obj_inv = $this->Inventario_model->insert_inventario($array_db); 
        if($obj_inv){           
            $edit_view = $this->load->view(base_url()."inventario/edit",$array_db,TRUE);
            $response = array('mensaje' => $edit_view,
                          );
            $this->output
                ->set_status_header(200)
                ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
                ->set_output(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES))
                ->_display();
        exit;
        }
```

This is part of the view page called create, this is the submit button that executes the Javascript code that execute the controller function

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_enviar" value="Guardar">
```

The javascript Function

```
$("#btn_enviar").click(function(){
        var r = confirm("Make sure the information you fill is correct");
        if (r == true){
            var url = base_url + "/inventario/insert_inventario";
                $.ajax({ 
                   type: "POST",
                   url: url,
                   data: $("#form_inventario").serialize(),
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                       $("#contenido").html(data.mensaje); 
                   }
                 });
        } 
            return false; 
 });
```

The problem is, when i fill the form and press submit, the message box appears and when I click accept, it does nothing. I'm burning my brain so much to understand what I'm doing wrong, please help me.

Comment: So Angel, are you sure you are pointing to the right url...what is the result of `console.log(url)` on the developer console?

Comment: It supposed, the create and edit are in the same view folder. (Create show first, then when you fill the information and submit it supposed to change to edit view. And i'm editing in notepad++ so i can't see the developer console

Comment: All `console.log` result shows in the Developer Console(on the web browser press F12 and choose the console tab)

Comment: Oh right, ok, it says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" and the  url says "/Inventario_Remedy/inventario/insert_inventario".  but insert_inventario is a function, not a controller, the controller is called "inventario"

Comment: Sorry Angel, it seems that the material you are using to learn CodeIgniter is plain wrong or not updated....If you want I can recommend you some textbooks or web site links

Comment: But why is the error happening? I'm new at Codeigniter by the way, i'm  still learning, sorry if I can be more accurate.

Comment: Always start from the basics...for example check if your method works....f.i : Comment all the code on your method and put this line: `echo "this is a test";`...then just invoke the url in the browser and see if the message shows...then start uncommenting your code piece by piece until you find the culprit :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i figure out the error... My partner didn't notice when he build the program didn't see it because it appears only in developer console. Its a problem with the database!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is a error called jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4 POST http://161.196.112.19:8080/Inventario_Remedy/inventario/insert_inventario 500 (Internal Server Error) it happens when the code try to insert the array

```
$obj_inv = $this->Inventario_model->insert_inventario($array_db);
```

So, in order to fix this, you have to check your database values and keep trying.